# Building android project with ant

Tags: android, ant, apk, acra

I am trying to build my android project using ant in command line mode.
It works with eclipse and it used to work with ant until i installed the latest android sdk.

I run `ant release -buildfile projectdir\build.xml`. The compilation process is ok, and after aligning the apk, it fails at runtime with `ClassDefNotFoundError acra.ACRA`.
I have tried to remove any reference to acra from the project, but it will fail at runtime when trying to execute any code coming from a library jar.

My jars are in the `libs` folder at the root of the project. And I sort of understood this would cause ant to link them into the apk. But it doesn't.

When I used a previous version of the android sdk, I had a file named `build.properties` with an attribute referencing the jars folder `external.libs.dir=libs`. But now I can't make this to work any more, even if I use the new attributes names `jar.libs.dir=libs` and the new attributes file name `ant.properties`.

I read that ClassDefNotFoundError is caused because at compile time the librairies are found, but they are not linked into the apk, so they can't be found at runtime.
How can I link the external jars in the apk please ?

Comment: Does your private build.xml make nay reference to "jar.libs.ref"?

Comment: No it doesn't mention this, and build.xml is generated by the android tool `android.bat`, not by me.

Comment: Oh well just a thought, I wondered if you still had an old r16 compatible build.xml. No suggestions from me I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes I will downgrade to r16 if I can't fix this, but i'd prefer not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The compilation process is ok, and after aligning the apk, it fails at runtime with ClassDefNotFoundError acra.ACRA

There is no `acra.ACRA` class in ACRA, at least not in the current edition. It's `org.acra.ACRA`.

> My jars are in the libs folder at the root of the project. And I sort of understood this would cause ant to link them into the apk. But it doesn't.

Yes, it does. Then ProGuard is removing them, [unless you teach ProGuard not to](http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/ACRAProGuardHowTo).

Comment: yes it is org.acra.ACRA, and I have already added those lines in proguard.cfg a long time ago, but now it doesn't work any more, since i have installed the latest android sdk.

Comment: You can see what i'm talking about in the link you have provided, where the last comment is exactly the issue I have. Unfortunately it doesn't come with an answer.

Comment: @Joel: If you are on the R17 tools, it no longer uses `proguard.cfg`: http://tools.android.com/recent/proguardimprovements  See whether adjusting to the new setup helps any. Also, you can test with `ant debug` to confirm that the problem is ProGuard-related.

Comment: I have tried ant debug and I get the same error. I really think the jars are not linked somehow. I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: @Joel: That's odd. I suggest starting a clean new project, trying to add ACRA, and seeing if it works. If it does (and it should), then something may be messed up in your project's configuration. Focus on `ant debug` first to keep ProGuard's mitts off of matters.

Comment: I understand but it's not proguard related obviously, and I don't even have any project configuration at all which could be messed up. I'm recreating the project configuration everytime with `android.bat update project ...` and the only files I have written are the source files which work when i use eclipse to build them.

Comment: @Joel: I don't know what to tell you. ACRA has been working for me just fine, on the R17 tools, from the command line using `ant release`. Despite that comment on that one page, I don't see an outstanding issue on the ACRA issue tracker related to this, though I just skimmed the titles. If you can create a sample project that reproduces your error, file an issue with the project.

Comment: Okay you have been very helpfull and I have tried a lot of things based on what you said. I have found how to fix this and I can never explain it: The windows system's current working directory has to be the project's directory when running ant, and then it works.

Comment: @Joel: Ah, you know, I think I saw a post on `adt-dev` mentioning that, though I'm not seeing it in the archives. I always build from the project directory, so I never notice any issues. My apologies for not thinking of that sooner.